# {{bindAttr }} {{action}} [Object] Has no method replace

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

when ember.js tries to render my template containing the following bindAttr. the following exception is thrown in handlebars.js

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'   handlebars.js:848
```

bind attr tag:

```
<div class="postWrapper" {{bindAttr style="display:none"}}>
```

**Update**

this also happens when i use the action helper

```
    <div {{action Toggle}}  class="btn pull-right">
        <i class="postToggler icon-chevron-down " ></i>
    </div>
```

***Update Full Code***

Template

```
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="Composer">
                <div class="postWrapper">
                                <div class="postContentWrapper" {{bindAttr style="controller.display"}}>  
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="pull-left span10">
                                        To :
                            <input id="test2" type="text" style="margin-top: 7px;width:90%" />
                    </div>
                    <div {{action Toggle}}  class="btn pull-right">
                        <i class="postToggler icon-chevron-down " ></i>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row-fluid" style="height:100%" >
                    <div id="wmd-button-bar" style="width:48%;display:inline-block" ></div>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                    <a>Hide preview</a>
                    </div>
                        <div class="wmdWrapper" style="height:80%">
                            <div class="wmd-panel" style="vertical-align: top;">

                                <textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input" style="height: 100%;"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-preview pull-right"></div>
                        </div>
                        <br />

                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">

                    <div class="span6  ">
                        <p>
                            Tags :
                            <input id="test" type="text" style="width:80%"/>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="span2 pull-right">
                        <button id="btnSubmitPost" class="btn btn-success pull-right">{{controller.buttonText}}</button>
                        <button id="btnCanelPost" class="btn btn-warning pull-right">Cancel</button>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </script>
```

View and render

```
        /*
        MODES
            NEW
            REPLY

        */
        Thoughts.ComposerController = Ember.Object.extend({
            mode: 2,
            visible: false,
            messageContent: "",
            buttonText: function () {
                switch (this.get("mode")) {
                    case 1: return "Post";
                    case 2: return "Reply";
                }
            }.property(),

            display: function () {
                if (this.get("visible")) {
                    return 'display:block';
                } else
                    return 'display:none';
            }.property(),

            Toggle: function(){
                console.log('Helllo');
                }
        });

        Thoughts.ComposerController = Thoughts.ComposerController.create();
```

**Error Information**

object dump

```
            string: "data-ember-action="1""
            __proto__: Object
            constructor: function (string) {
            toString: function () {
            __proto__: Object
```

Crashes on the replace method, because the method replace is undefined

```
Handlebars.Utils = {
    escapeExpression: function (string) {
        // don't escape SafeStrings, since they're already safe
        if (string instanceof Handlebars.SafeString) {
            return string.toString();
        } else if (string == null || string === false) {
            return "";
        }

        if (!possible.test(string)) { return string; }
       ----> return string.replace(badChars, escapeChar);
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found some time to work on this again.

all i did was replace the ember and handlebars js files, and the code is working fine now thanks

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you need to define only need to define the controller. You don't have to create an instance. Ember will do it for you when application initialize.

If you define a property that is observing another in other words its value depends on another, you need this to specify as parameter to `property` helper.

```
Thoughts.ComposerController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    mode: 2,
    visible: false,
    messageContent: "",

    buttonText: function () {
        switch (this.get("mode")) {
            case 1: return "Post";
            case 2: return "Reply";
        }
    }.property('mode'),

    display: function () {
        return 'display:' + this.get('visible') ? 'block' : 'none';
    }.property('visible'),

    Toggle: function () {
        this.toggleProperty('visible');
        this.set('mode', this.get('mode') == 2 ? 1 : 2);
    }
});
```

Template itself seems valid.

You can get this working by creating a composer route like this:

```
this.route('composer');
```

or by rendering it in another template like this:

```
{{render 'composer'}}
```

That should be answer to your question. **BUT**

Wouldn't be better to use `{{if}}` helper for showing some content inside of template based on a condition?

Comment: ye, i am just using that as an example the display is going to be variable depending on the state of the controller, but it doesn't work with the static or the dynamic, and throws the same exception

Comment: How did you compiled your template? Do you have more code to show?

Comment: the composer is available on all routes, that's why i need to initialize its controller. ye i think an if may be better, but the issue still exists with {{action}}, so still want to try solve it

Comment: What is the issue with `{{action}}`. Does it throw error? Have you tried lowercase the name `Toggle`?

Comment: ye i have, i have updated the question with more information, its throwing the same error as bind attr